# Why am I not able to receive a REST response from my Spark server via this JavaScript? (Hello World!)

Tags: javascript, spark-java

I have the simplest Spark server set up. It listens to requests and responds with a simple json message.

I also have a very simple web page that makes a request to the Spark "hello world" REST URL.

If I request the URL in my Chrome browser I get the response as expected. However from JavaScript I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong? Is it not able to connect because it's on localhost? What do I do?

I have the following Spark application:

```
import static spark.Spark.get;
import static spark.Spark.port;

public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        port(7675);
        get("/hello", (req, res)->{
            System.out.println("Hello");
            res.type("application/json");
            return "Hello";
        });
    }
}
```

And I have the following JavaScript:

```
function onLoad(){
    alert("Loaded")
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:7675/hello/",  false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    try{
        xhttp.send();
    } catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Working in the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testPage.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="testPage.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I load the page I get the following alert from the catch clause:

```
NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':Failed to load 'http://localhost:7675/hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers implement a security feature called [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) which you need to enable in Spark. There's a tutorial on how to do that [here](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2016/05/01/cors.html)